# Debian Bluetooth headphones not working

Tags: linux, debian, bluetooth, alsa

## Hardware

- [Headphones](http://www.b-speech.de/en/produkt-information/archiv/archiv-b-speech_calypso/)
- [Bluetooth dongle](http://www.hamletcom.com/products/hbtus.aspx)

*Maybe not exactly these models.*

## Setup

I tried to follow [some](http://wiki.debian.org/Bluetooth/Alsa) [guides](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_Headset), here's what I've done so far:

Install software:

```
sudo apt-get install bluez-utils bluez-alsa
```

Reboot (just to be sure):

```
$ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[   20.268212] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[   20.268230] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   20.268233] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   20.268235] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   20.268239] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   20.284685] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   20.284692] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   20.284693] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   20.335375] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   20.335378] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
```

The deamon is running:

```
$ /etc/init.d/bluetooth status
[ ok ] bluetooth is running.
```

Plug the dongle:

```
$ dmesg | tail
[...]
[23108.352034] usb 5-2: new full-speed USB device number 2 using ohci_hcd
[23108.571131] usb 5-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0a12, idProduct=0001
[23108.571136] usb 5-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[23108.629042] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
```

Put the headphones in pairing mode, and try scanning:

```
$ hcitool scan
Scanning ...
```

Found nothing. What's next? What should I try? I'll update this answer as soon as you provide me hints.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your (old) Bluetooth dongle is incompatible with your headset, because it's just Bluetooth v1.1, while your headset is v2.0+. This is based on the information your provided in your links.

So, first try using another dongle.

Comment: I managed to successfully scan for that device *just one time* (showing me `Calypso xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`) but I wasn't able to repeat, anyway I'll try that.

Comment: No, it turns out that the headset itself was buggy, another one worked correctly even with the Bluetooth v1.1 dongle.